# Determine if the user clicked inside the polygon or outside of it

Tags: matlab

I am trying to write a script in Matlab that fills a polygon and prints "inside" to the output window when the user clicks inside the polygon and "outside" to the output window when the user clicks outside the polygon.  For some reason it prints inside even when I click outside the polygon.  I have put my code below.

```
xv = [ -3 3 3 -3]; %// x coords of polygon vertices. Arbitrary number
yv = [-5 -5 7 7]; %// y coords of polygon vertices. Same number as for x
fill(xv,yv,'b') %// draw polygon
axis([-10 10 -10 10])
[xp, yp] = ginput(1); %// get point coordinates
inside = inpolygon(xp,yp,xv,yv); %// is it inside?

while inside
    fprintf('Inside\n')
    [xp, yp] = ginput(1);
end
    fprintf('Outside\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is missing the line in the `while` loop to reset the value of `inside`, checking to see if the user input is still in the polygon:

```
while inside
    fprintf('Inside\n')
    [xp, yp] = ginput(1);
    inside = inpolygon(xp,yp,xv,yv); %// is it inside?
end

% outside the polygon, so finished
fprintf('Outside\n')
```

And so once the user has clicked outside the polygon, the script terminates.